# $_GET does not seem to work properly & returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from my database with $_GET statements but it returns nothing from db at all! What I mean by that is nothing shows up ... no error message & no properties!

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['hash'])&&!empty($_GET['hash'])){
    echo "Show Messages:";
}
else {
    echo "Select Message:";
    $get_con = "SELECT `hash`,`user_one`,`user_two` FROM `message_group` WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'";
    $take_con = mysqli_query($con,$get_con);
    while($row_con = mysqli_fetch_array($take_con)){
        $hash = $row_con['hash'];
        $user_one = $row_con['user_one'];
        $user_two = $row_con['user_two'];

        if ($user_one == $my_id){
            $select_id = $user_two;
        }
        else {
            $select_id = $user_one;
        }
        $user_get = "SELECT username FROM admins WHERE id='$select_id'";
        $run_user = mysqli_query($con,$user_get);
        while($row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            $select_username = $row_user['username'];

        echo "</br><a href='messages.php?hash=$hash'>$select_username</a>";
    }
}

?>
```

As you can see the `<a href='messages.php?hash=$hash'>$select_username</a>` link is referencing to the **messages.php**  which is the same page & it should echo out `"Show Messages:"` because the `(isset($_GET['hash'])` is already set & it's not empty as well!

Comment: Hello! Please add print_r($_GET) at the top of you page, then you can see what is saved in your GET variables

Comment: You absolutely don't need to use the first `isset`, because the `empty` already checks whether the variable is set and whether it's "empty".

Comment: Replace the `echo`s with `die`s and tell me what you get.

Comment: Is the data in the echo'd link what you would expect? Try testing with a return which passes back the value and outputs it to console or a messagebox, is it passing back the hash you sent or is it blank?

Comment: It looks most likely that you're not actually populating the link. You can also just use if(isset($_GET['hash'])) to see if hash has any data.

Answer (score 0):

In the link, try:

```
"<a href='messages.php?hash='".$hash."'>$select_username</a>"
```

occasionally php do

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things to make it work:

1. Print print_r($_GET) on the top of the page to see if you are getting the values in $_GET
2. Make sure your DB connection is working properly.
3. The concatenation in your queries are wrong use below:

   ```
   $get_con = "SELECT `hash`,`user_one`,`user_two` FROM `message_group` WHERE user_one='".$my_id."' OR user_two='".$my_id."'";

   $user_get = "SELECT username FROM admins WHERE id='".$select_id."'";

   echo "</br><a href='messages.php?hash='.$hash>".$select_username."</a>";
   ```